Как использовать динамический ip в настройках ftp на iis'е?
Я настроил ftp на iis'е и вроде бы всё работает.
Но есть нюанс: хотя провайдер предоставляет мне белый ip, этот ip динамический, а значит меняется с каждой перезагрузкой роутера (ну или по другим причинам). У меня есть настроенный на роутере динамический dns, например (на самом дели имя другое), smth.ddns.net, по которому можно обратиться к ftp.
Проблема в том, что при настройке iis'а на шаге 9 надо было указать ip-адрев, выданный провайдером:

Поэтому каждый раз при смене этого адреса надо лезть в настройки iis и менять его там.
Как этого можно избежать?
Я пытался указать доменное имя вместо ip, но iis его не принимает.
