FTP не спрашивает пароль
Есть FTP на IIS, к нему подключаюсь через белый IP c логином/паролем через стандартный проводник Windows. На одном! из компов папка FTP отрубилась и при коннекте не спрашивает пароль почему-то. Самое интересное - на других компьютерах высе работает.
Пробовал удалить ветку реестра HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software, Microsoft, FTP, Accounts > мой фтп - но не помогло. Прошу помощи.

Вы же можете логин (а можно и сразу пароль, но не нужно, пусть лучше оно его спросит) указать при коннекте к ftp. Что-то типа ftp://login@site, попробуйте, может оно переспросит и пароль тогда.

@CrazyElf хм, так заработало, спасибо, что-то в винде видимо где-то багнуло

А ты смог как-то внешний ip настроить? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1423203/178988

@Happyraccoon Ну, видимо, сохранённые креденшелы заэкспайрились и оно анонимусом заходило, как у ftp принято по дефолту. Я и с заходом на просто шары сталкивался с похожим глюком - пока прямо не укажешь заходить таким-то пользователем, оно не пойми кем заходит и логин-пароль не переспрашивает.
